# I don't write my partitions please help me

Tags: disk-management, full-disk-encryption

After the update, access to my previous disks was disabled. and now I don't write these partitions. how to fix this error and how to write my disk partition?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they are mounted as read-only or you (the user) don't have enough privileges to write on those.

Try one easy thing first: Hit the 'eject' button next to the partition you are trying to write on. If it allows you to do it (un-mount it) then click on it again to re-mount it and try to write to it again. It might ask for your 'sudo' password to perform that operation.

If that fails, umount-them manually from a command line:

- Go to a terminal
- Type 'df -h' to see the mounted partitions
- identify the one you want to un-mount (example /dev/sdb2 with a mount path of /run/media/user/234234234/Part_Label).
- run 'sudo umount /dev/sdb2'

If that works, go to the file manager and click on the partition so it mounts it again with your username. That might do the trick for you.

best,

-Aldo